# Set up a syslog server

Tags: server, syslog

I have installed Ubuntu Server 12.04 and I intend to set up a syslog server. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/

Answer (score 1):

Go grab a copy of [LogZilla](http://www.logzilla.pro) - it's free for small networks, and super easy!